# Colour in muriate of Potash?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Alkali earth metals produce white coloured salts with halogens like chlorine. But Muriate of potassium available in India generally used as a fertilizer is pink coloured(reddish white actually), why is it so?

Comment: You found your nomenclature in XIX century book? Or older?

Comment: Yes muriatic acid is an old name of HCl. Muriatic means brine, but for strange reason muriatic earth is magnesium oxide :)

Comment: If it’s sold as a fertilizer, it probably won’t be pure KCl. In addition, it may be coloured pink on purpose so it isn’t mistaken for table salt.

Comment: The color is due to iron oxides as impurities.

Comment: Related: [How is Persian blue rock salt made?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/how-is-persian-blue-rock-salt-made)

Answer (score 3):

If you have seen pink salt crystals from Khewra mines in Pakistan (the so-called Himalayan pink salt) sold at exorbitant rates in grocery stores, you would find out it is nothing but NaCl with a small amount of iron oxides as stated above. If you dissolve large tablespoons of such salt crystals in water, you will see a brownish precipitate sitting at the bottom on the container.

The word muriate reminded me of ancient chemistry books of the 1940s. It is a very very old name for a salt of hydrochloric acid.